# NestJS: Unable to resolve dependencies of a shared library during e2e tests

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm, nx-monorepo

I am working with an Nx monorepo, which includes several NestJS applications and a shared library. The shared library contains a custom subscriber MinimalClass, which is imported to one my NestJS apps via the AppModule's imports. While the NestJS app runs fine, its e2e tests fail due to dependency resolution issues related to this subscriber.

The relevant code snippets are as follows:

**MinimalSubscriber**:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class MinimalSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<any> {
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {   
    connection.subscribers.push(this);
  }
}
```

**MinimalSubscriberModule**:

```
@Module({
  providers: [MinimalSubscriber],
  exports: [MinimalSubscriber],
})
export class MinimalSubscriberModule {}
```

This module is imported in the NestJS app's **AppModule**:

```
@Module({
  imports: [MinimalSubscriberModule /* more imports */],
  // controllers, providers, etc.
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When running e2e tests, I encounter the following error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MinimalSubscriber (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the MinimalSubscriberModule context.

I use TypeOrmModule.forRoot() during the e2e test setup in my e2e.helper.ts file:

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(getConfig(pg.port(), pg.host())),
    AppModule,
  ],
})
  .overrideProvider(HttpService)
  .useClass(MockHttpService)
  .compile();
```

(Note that here pg is a postgres container spun up with testcontainers.)

This getConfig method is defined in orm.config.ts:

```
export const getConfig = (
  port = 5432,
  host = process.env["POSTGRES_HOST"] ?? "localhost"
) => {
  // dotenv setup and more config
  return {
    type: "postgres",
    host,
    port,
    entities: [__dirname + "/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    // more config
  };
};
```

This error only occurs during e2e tests, but not when the application is run normally with the same TypeOrmModule.forRoot() call.

Is there something I'm missing in my e2e test setup that would allow NestJS to properly resolve the Connection dependency in the shared library's MinimalSubscriber?